# Clean SVG files with PHP

Tags: php, vector, svg

is it possible to clean svg with PHP?

I want to remove elements and attributes that don't contribute to the final rendering.

The goal is to create svg files with only the necessary code (no colors, only black and white, no css styles and only the forms (circle square lines)).

Comment: `don't contribute to the final rendering` is subjective. SVG is a parsed format by whatever program the user is using. So if a SVG application does decide that some meta tags will change the render, then removing it would change the end result.

Comment: Agreed with @DaveChen, what could you possibly need to clean from the said SVG files?

Comment: SVG documents are XML documents, so it's possible to modify them with PHP using XMLReader, SimpleXML or SAX.